# FasterXML - Jackson XML extension translate values to null in pojo

Tags: java, xml, jackson, fasterxml, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have decided to give Jackson XML a chance in my project for converting XML strings to POJO's.

So I used the following great [web site](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) to generate pojo's from my xml string.

So, it created the classes I needed and then I tried to read the xml values into those objects.

Unfortunately, some of the values were set as null in the objects and I cannot figure out why:

This is the beginning of the xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schedule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" generated_at="2018-02-23T16:55:45+00:00" xmlns="http://schemas.thesite.com/jobsapi/v1/myjob" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.thesite.com/jobsapi/v1/myjob http://schemas.thesite.com/asb/myjob/v1/xml/endpoints/myjob/schedule.xsd">
    <job_event id="sr:task:12004724" scheduled="2018-02-23T17:00:00+00:00" start_time_tbd="false" status="not_started">
        <task type="group" number="23"/>
```

And the classes I have are:

```
public class Schedule
{
    private String generated_at;
    private String xmlns;
    private Job_event[] job_events;

    public String getGenerated_at ()
    {
        return generated_at;
    }

    public void setGenerated_at (String generated_at)
    {
        this.generated_at = generated_at;
    }

    public String getXmlns ()
    {
        return xmlns;
    }

    public void setXmlns (String xmlns)
    {
        this.xmlns = xmlns;
    }

    public Job_event[] getjob_events ()
    {
        return job_events;
    }

    public void setjob_events (Job_event[] job_events)
    {
        this.job_events = job_events;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Schedule [generated_at = "+generated_at+", xmlns = "+xmlns+", job_events = "+job_events+"]";
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Job_event {

    private String id;
    private String scheduled;
    private String start_time_tbd;
    private String status;

        //more fields, getters and setters   
}
```

Then, I use this to convert the string to pojos:

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Schedule sched = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlString, Schedule.class);
Job_event[] job_events = sched.getJob_events();
```

And there I find in each event value in job_events that the member values like id and status and the rest are null.

Why is that? The xml string is ok.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix it by doing the following

1. Use `@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)` annotation to map Pojo fields to XML attributes
2. Use `List` instead of Array
3. Use `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` annotation to signal that your list `List<JobEvent>` is represented as repeated XML element.
4. I also think you should [annotate your fields](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki/Jackson-XML-annotations) with `localName`, in order to stay compatible to Java naming conventions

After that it will look like

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JobEvent {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String id;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String scheduled;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "start_time_tbd")
    private String startTimeTbd;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String status;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " " + scheduled + " " + " " + startTimeTbd + " " + status;
    }
}
```

Schedule.java

```
public class Schedule {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true,localName="generated_at")
    public String generatedAt;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public String xmlns;
     @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public List<JobEvent> job_event;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Schedule [generated_at = "+generatedAt+", xmlns = "+xmlns+", job_events = "+job_event.toString()+"]";
    }
}
```

Testcall

```
@Test
    public void readXmlToSelfDefinedPojo2() throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        Schedule pojo = mapper.readValue(
                        Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("48963966.xml"),
                        Schedule.class);
        System.out.println(pojo + "");
    }
```

For an XML file 48963966.xml

Will print

```
Schedule [generated_at = 2018-02-23T16:55:45+00:00, xmlns = null, job_events = [sr:task:12004724 2018-02-23T17:00:00+00:00  false not_started, sr:task:12004725 2018-02-25T17:00:00+00:00  false not_started]]
```